# When I am trying to compile my program I get an error that the protection level is not match- Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#

When I am trying to compile my program I get an error that the protection level is not match between class players and varience color but I do have a match they are both public so I don't understend what the problem is.

Thanks

```
public class players
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Colors color { get; set; }


    // public string outPlayer;

    public players(string name, Colors color)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.color =color;
    }
}

enum Colors { black, wight }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Colours` enum has no accessibility modifier on it which means it defaults to `private. Just make it`public`:

```
public enum Colors { black, wight }
```